# JPA environment populate tables

Tags: java, database, swing, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA-2 in my swing project. I want to create and drop the table but every time I want to populate the database with my own either sql file or java beans. I could not find any configuration which help me to solve this problem. I am using Hibernate JPA implementation. When the context of the JPA load it must execute the insert data before application launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can put into root of your classpath import.sql file containing sql commands.
import.sql should be executed aftter ddl schema generation is completed